# IE8 html image alignment

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, alignment, ie8-compatibility-mode

Currently all browsers are showing my page correctly except IE8, which is having a mystery alignment issue.

I already added the meta that worked for previous questions:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

However this has not fixed the problem.

Can you please look at my page to see if anything looks incorrect?

http://oldcalifornia.com/Exterior_Craftsman.asp

Thank you,
Robert

Comment: do you have alignment issue?

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML and CSS code here instead of linking to your website. As it is, your question risks being closed due to being too vague/broad.

Comment: Please DO NOT link to your web site. Here's why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Throw the html code away and don't use tables for layout.

Answer (score 3):

Your site is designed using tables, tables shouldn't be used for anything except displaying tabular data. Consider redesigning your site using divs.

Comment: Agree. You could almost use that big sliced image as an one-file background to decrease server requests and put your paragraphs in a div over it. But if you really need to use tables, I would suggest to re-create it slicing in some another way...

Answer (score -1):

I have also suffered this issue. Add standard `doctype` declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

I am not sure, but try if this would work.